# Map glitched, can't scroll/zoom in Far Cry 3

Tags: far-cry-3

I'm having a problem in FC3 where when I open the map it suddenly gets stuck like it doesn't know where the center of it is, and it only allows me to scroll on the left side of the map but not towards it.
I'm currently using v1.04 of the game, but this has been happening to me since v1.02

How can I solve this and zoom in and out again?

Answer (score 2):

[This Steam Forums discussion](http://steamcommunity.com/app/220240/discussions/0/864973980869224640/) says that a workaround is to press the Alt key to bring up the map legend, and then again to return to the map (which should now work).  I can't verify this, because I haven't seen the glitch again since I discovered the workaround.